# Zend View Helper Error :Plugin by name 'Slideshow' was not found in the registry

Tags: zend-framework

I have an application written in Zend Framework envelopment , I want to add a view helper in my default module by adding these codes :

application/modules/default/views/helpers/slideshow.php :

```
class Default_View_Helper_Slideshow extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract

{

    public function slideshow()
    {

    }

}
```

application/Bootstrap.php :

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    public function _initViewHelperPath() {
        
        $this->bootstrap('view');
        $view = $this->getResource('view');

          $view->addHelperPath(
                APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default/views/helpers/',
                'Default_View_Helper');
 }
```

application/modules/default/views/scripts/index/index.phtml:

```
<?php $this->slideshow(); ?>
```

and getting this error :

> Message:
>
> Plugin by name 'Slideshow' was not found in the registry; used paths:
> Default_View_Helper_:
> /var/www/go/application/modules/default/views/helpers/
> Zend_View_Helper_:
> Zend/View/Helper/:/var/www/go/application/modules/default/views/helpers/

What should i do to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename of your helper should be `application/modules/default/views/helpers/Slideshow.php` (note the capital 'S').

Comment: thank's .All Helper should be that way or i miss config something ?

Comment: All helpers should be that way. The standard ZF helpers work in the same way.